# Reg Executing C++ applications on U-Boot (No OS)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, u-boot

We have developed an application which has so many C++ files. On Linux we were able to execute it.

We have an U-Boot for the MPC8548E based custom board.
Now we decided to go without OS. So, I tried two methods to execute the C++ applications on U-Boot.

1.) Compiled the C++ application with the g++ (C++ cross-compiler) and tried to link with the U-Boot, which is compiled using gcc (The C-Compiler). But I am unable to do that:
The error message I am seeing is:
/ToolChain/host/usr/powerpc-buildroot-linux-uclibcspe/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file...
2.) Tried to compile my application along with U-Boot in the same way the standalone examples are done. I created a separate directory in the U-Boot and tried to compile it. C++ applications are not getting built, but I am able to build C-Applications.

My main intention is to execute C++ applications directly on U-Boot.
Please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I believe it would be more work to get C++ on U-Boot than it would be for you to e.g. go with OS.

The [short answer](http://u-boot.10912.n7.nabble.com/U-Boot-Building-C-Examples-td71586.html), from U-Boot tech lead:

```
> Does u-boot support C++ example programs and if so, how can I build one? 
U-Boot does not support C++.
```

Some of the technical background for this: U-Boot runs on bare metal. A U-Boot standalone application would link to U-Boot's exported functions which the application needs. For example, your C++ application would use 'new', your C++ library needs to perform calls to malloc, which in this case would mean going to the u-boot exported function interface (refer to doc/README.standalone).

For the general topic of C++ on bare metal, I have not done that, but found [Miro Samek](http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4007119/Building-Bare-Metal-ARM-Systems-with-GNU-Part-1--Getting-Started) tutorial that may shed light. I think it would be difficult. Porting linux starts to look good in comparison.

Comment: Hi Joe Kul,
Even, I read the same short answer which you mentioned in your answer.
Coming to your answer, the point is that I have used only the “Classes” concept in the C++ application. There are no malloc kind of calls. The only calls I am going to make is “printf”.
So, Is it possible for me to do some modifications and execute the C++ applications on U-Boot.
FYI, Porting Linux and executing my application on the target with Linux is done and it is working fine. But now the requirement is to remove the OS dependent part of code and run the application as standalone.

Comment: Maybe you want to redefine your goal: a C++ application that you want to run without an OS, on bare metal. It happens that you will load/run it with U-Boot. So, you can dispense with some low-level HW init e.g. memory controller and clocks. You may choose to hook to some of U-Boot's API, but that's probably not the hardest part. Miro Samek tutorial is spot-on for your needs; but there are lots of hard parts there. And, even with you just using classes, I suspect you will find that the C++ compiler is doing more things behind your back than you were aware of.